# adding HTTP module for IP logging

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm confused about how to properly add an HTTP handler, especially in the web.config file.

I have this:

```
public class MySessionHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    public bool IsReusable { get { return false; } }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.Write("my custom handler.");
    }
}
```

What do I need to put in the web config file so that this gets executed on every request. Basically, I've got a linq-to-sql query that stores the IP address of every request that I want to get executed every time. For now, it's on the page load event of the master page but I'd like to use an HTTP handler.

Also, if I do this, will this execute when I'm calling the server with a jQuery .ajax call?

Thanks?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could implement a HttpModule and hook into the HttpApplication.BeginRequest Event that fires on each request,like:

```
/// <summary>
/// Summary description for MyModule
/// </summary>
public class MyModule : IHttpModule
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.BeginRequest += new EventHandler(context_BeginRequest);
    }

    private void context_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpApplication application = (HttpApplication)sender;
        HttpContext context = application.Context;
        String ip = context.Request.UserHostAddress;
        //... code to log IP address
    }
}
```

... and then in your web.config:

```
   <httpModules>
      <add name="IPAddressLogger" type="MyModule, MyAssembly"/>
   </httpModules>
```

Comment: ok, great, that's exactly what I was looking for. Will it also for for ajax requests? Thanks a lot, your answer will have a good google page rank soon!!

Comment: Yes, the BeginRequest event is raised for every request, including ajax requests.

Answer (score 4):

A handler is mapped to a specified file name extension. If you want something to execute for every request, you want an HttpModule. There's more [information on when to use an HttpHandler vs. an HttpModule here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398986.aspx).

Registering a handler for an extension, such as .ajax, depends on what version of IIS you're running under. [The MSDN documentation explains the different cases](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/46c5ddfy.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

simplest thing you can do is add a "Generic Handler" from the "New Item..." dialog.  you will add a file to your project with an ashx extension and it will have the same class defined in its "code behind", handler.ashx.cs

addressable as: ~\handler.ashx

Comment: sorry, didnt know that's what you wanted to do.  The other requests may be a better approach.  Mine just shows how to make a "handler" without additional configuration.

Comment: ok, no problem; I'll look into handlers in detail. What are they generally for?

Comment: I use them for async file downloads, or for "export as [format]...".  It basically enables async requests to the server that returns some other content type besides html.

Comment: Ah, so for instance, when a user wants to download a .csv file export; do u then generate the csv file, save it as a name that you send the browser, which then calls back the handler with the filename as parameter and the handler replies with the correct csv file. Is that a good way to do it?

Comment: That's the basic idea.  If you are working with a filetype that you can generate in-memory then you dont have to save it to disk.  Instead you can stream bytes to the response buffer and give it a default name